# WebApp2: TypeError: get() takes exactly 1 argument (2 given)

Tags: python-2.7, google-app-engine, jinja2, webapp2

After user registration i would like to redirect to a welcome page with url "../user/abcxyz" where abcxyz would be the username. However on redirect page I get the following error:

```
return method(*args, **kwargs)
TypeError: get() takes exactly 1 argument (2 given)
```

Following is the relevant part of the code:

```
class Signup(MainHandler):
  ...
  ...
  # after successful signup redirect to welcome page 
  self.redirect('/user/%s' % username)
```

---

```
class WelcomeHandler(MainHandler):
   def get(self):
       self.render('welcome.html')
```

---

```
def render_str(template, **params):
    t = JINJA_ENVIRONMENT.get_template(template)
    return t.render(params)


class MainHandler(webapp2.RequestHandler):
    """ Class for handelling account register, login, etc."""

    def write(self, *a, **kw):
        self.response.out.write(*a, **kw)

    def render_str(self, template, **params):
        return render_str(template, **params)

    def render(self, template, **kw):
        self.write(self.render_str(template, **kw))
```

---

```
app = webapp2.WSGIApplication([
(r'/', HomeHandler),
            (r'/user/(.*)', WelcomeHandler),
            (r'/signup', Signup)
        ], debug=True)
```

I went through many [similar](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/42506944/webapp2-typeerror-get-takes-exactly-1-argument-2-given) questions asked before but not found any answer relevant to my problem. Please help me fix this error.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

It's because of the capturing group, that you have used in the route regex.

```
(r'/user/(.*)', WelcomeHandler),
```

this would capture the string which follows `/user/` and then passed to the corresponding request method `get` or `post` as second parameter.

So you have to modify the request method exists in the corresponding handler like below.

```
class WelcomeHandler(MainHandler):
   def get(self, username):
       self.render('welcome.html')
```

if you want to pass the `username` to the `welcome.html` page, then

```
def get(self, username):
    self.render('welcome.html', username=username)
```

Comment: Awesome, Thanks.